# TypeError: argument 'names': 'float' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to rename columns using the other DataFrame's column value, then I got this error.

How to rename the column name? Thanks

```py
df_value = df_polar_parquet.select(pl.col('*').exclude('Depth'))
df_value_transpose = df_value.transpose(include_header=False)
df_value_transpose.columns = df_polar_parquet['Depth'].to_list()
df_value_transpose
```

gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heatmap_comparison_polars_pandas2.py", line 3
    df_value_transpose.columns = df['Depth'].to_list()
  File "polars/dataframe/frame.py", line 1192, in DataFrame.columns(self, names)
   1180 @columns.setter
   1181 def columns(self, names: Sequence[str]) -> None:
   1182     """
   1183     Change the column names of the `DataFrame`.
   (...)
   1191     """
-> 1192     self._df.set_column_names(names)

TypeError: argument 'names': 'float' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
```

Comment: Your `Depth` column is of type `float`, you can cast to a string: `df.columns = df['Depth'].cast(str)`